# how to get response from Atmosphere framework without any actions done from user

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat7, atmosphere

I'm using struts2 integrated with spring framework for my application,  I need to get a response from server side without the action done by the user. That is like pull technology. so i preferred Atmosphere Framework becoz it is a push framework and i've work out the example from this [link](https://github.com/jfarcand/atmosphere/blob/master/samples/jquery-pubsub/src/main/webapp/index.html)

but in that example im getting response for any action done by me. but i need without any  action i've to get response like text appear in jsp by invoking query or any other method. please check and help to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Server-Side-Broadcasts--OR-Communication-from-Server-Sides--OR--Non-Http-initiated-Broadcast). Mainly, you must use the BroadcasterFactory.